# Does not having a reference to a Task cause memory leaks?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, task-parallel-library

Consider the following code snippet:

```
public void Do()
{
   ....
   Task.Delay(5000).ContinueWith(t => DoSomething());
   ....
}
```

Assume that the `Do` method finishes execution before the `Delay` task is finished and that `DoSomething` is not cancelable.

Does the fact that no reference is being maintained to the `Task` returned by `ContinueWith` method cause some kind of memory leak?

Comment: You could say the same thing if your code were just `Task.Delay(5000);` - _"no reference is being maintained to the Task returned"_ and I'm pretty sure that doesn't leak.

Comment: I don't think you could actually leak memory in managed context at all even if you want. When an instance of reference type has no reference to it, GC will come and collect it eventually.

Comment: Although not a leak, your task will be "unobserved", and unobserved tasks cause confusion if any exception is thrown. It can only be detected by the task finaliser, which runs during garbage collection at an uncontrollable time. So I'd still recommend rewriting your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The task will be executed on a thread pool thread, once the task is completed the thread will be returned to the pool for use by another task.

Thread pool threads are reclaimed after they've been idle for a period of time (around 45 seconds by default I think).

So the fact that the thread pool holds a reference to it will prevent it from being garbage collected.

The only caveat I guess is that the main application thread has to be running. If you ran the above code in a console app for example the execution would complete before the task, so the task would never run.

In short, no - that code will not cause a memory leak.

Comment: thanks, good explaination. What about long running tasks that are not from the thread pool?

Comment: Do you mean the LongRunning flag? If so, this just provides a hint to the scheduler that it might want to execute the task on a non-thread pool thread. Even if it does get executed on a non-thread pool thread it will still be a managed thread and will get cleaned up after its execution has completed. Also, Stephen Cleary indicates in this article that you probably don't need the LongRunning flag in most scenarios as the scheduler is able to adjust to any long-running task in 0.5 seconds: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html

Answer (score 12):

Can you leak (managed) memory by creating new tasks that don't get collected?
**Yes.**

Does keeping a reference to it (or not) have any effect on it being collected?
**Usually* not.**

There are 2 types of Tasks: Promise (async) tasks and Delegate (sync) tasks.

- Promise tasks (like `Task.Delay`) usually don't get collected as something keeps a reference to it so it can change its state when it needs to (in `Task.Delay` it's the internal `Timer` that needs to complete the `Task` when the delay ends).
- Delegate tasks ([as RagtimeWilly explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29272597/885318)) are referenced by the thread (and `TaskScheduler`) that's running them.

So, if you keep creating tasks you can have a leak whether you're holding a reference or not.

In your specific case, for the first 5 seconds, the internal `Timer` references the Promise `Task` which in turn references the Delegate `Task` (which isn't yet scheduled and doesn't have a thread associated with it). After 5 seconds the `Timer` completes the `Task.Delay` task which in turn schedules the `DoSomething` continuation and so a thread would reference it.

If `DoSomething` never completes you have a memory leak (a very small one), if it does complete then you don't.

---

<sup>*</sup> You **can** create tasks (of both kinds) that are only referenced by you and when you don't reference them anymore they can be collected by the `GC`. So while this:

```
static void Main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Task.Delay(int.MaxValue);
    }
}
```

Will result in a `OutOfMemoryException` in a matter of seconds, this can run forever:

```
static void Main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        new Task(() => Thread.Sleep(int.MaxValue)); // No thread as the task isn't started.
        Task.Delay(-1); // No Timer as the delay is infinite.
    }
}
```

Comment: `Task.Delay(-1)` will also cause memory leak in a similar matter to `Task.Delay(int.MaxValue)` (at the very least on .NET 4.6)

Comment: @marchewek What do you think this will leak? Instances of which class?